# jQuery columnizer newsletter example with last few paragraph not split?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery columnizer's newsletter example 10 http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

This is working fine creating a newsletter style HTML page with 2 columns of paragraphs from the content within `#newsletterContent`

I now need to have the content of another div with id bios added to the end of the columns on the very last page where the content end but only span one column and not be split.

I've tried adding `jQuery('#bios').columnize({columns:1,target: ".page:last .content"});` to the end of my javascript but because the bios div tag is within #newsletterContent it's continuing as one column but in the right hand column of #newsletterContent. So it's basically being placed into the last column on the last page at the end of the content.

Using jQuery appendTo is something I thought of and putting the bios div tag outside the newsletterContent div tag but then i'm not sure how to have it's content continue right when the newsletter content ends, and also create the pages should the bio's field run on to two pages.

HTML

jQuery
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            //var firstpage = $("div.first_page").html();
            //alert(firstpage);

```
        var content_height = 800;   // the height of the content, discluding the header/footer
        var page = 1;               // the beginning page number to show in the footer
        function buildNewsletter(){
            if($('#newsletterContent').contents().length > 0){
                // when we need to add a new page, use a jq object for a template
                // or use a long HTML string, whatever your preference
                $page = $("#page_template").clone().addClass("page").css("display", "block");

                // fun stuff, like adding page numbers to the footer
                $page.find(".footer span").append(page);
                $("body").append($page);
                page++;

                // here is the columnizer magic
                $('#newsletterContent').columnize({
                    columns: 2,
                    target: ".page:last .content",
                    overflow: {
                        height: content_height,
                        id: "#newsletterContent",
                        doneFunc: function(){
                            console.log("done with page");
                            buildNewsletter();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        setTimeout(buildNewsletter, 0);
    });
```

** Edit **
I tried using this to append the bios overflows past the footer of the final page and does not generate a new page. The css change I commented out created the bio in one column but same problem not extra page was generated when it overflowed. What can I change to make it create the page?

```
else {
    $(".page:last .last.column").append($("#bios"));
    //$('#bios').columnize({columns:1});
    //$("#bios").parents(".last.column").css( "width", "100%" );
    if ($(".page:last .last.column").height() > 800) {
        buildNewsletter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the #bios to be on its own page at the end of the document, inside of 1 column, I believe you can do that with code like: https://gist.github.com/adamwulf/7454134

If instead you'd like the #bios to be appended to the first column of the last page (which would assume the last page's content is short enough to handle the additional height of #bios without overflowing), then you can simply add an `else` clause to the `buildNewsletter()` if statement:

```
}else{
    $(".page:last .first.column").append($("#bios"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I already have the #bios content being added to an individual last page which is nice in case it overflows. Is there any solution to append the bios directly below the last page's content and allow it to overflow if the last page content or bios is longer than a page. Can #bios be appended to the last column then use an if condition that if the content is longer than 1 page add a new page?

Comment: you could do something like: `$(".page:last .last.column").append($("#bios"));` and then check `$(".page:last .last.column").height()` to see if its taller than it should be. if so, then that would trigger the above solution of adding a new page.

Comment: thanks I tried that but the bios is overflowing past the footer of the last page and not generating a new page. I edited my post to show what i've tried both your example and using jQuery to modify the CSS of the bios columns. I'd make a jsfiddle but it seems to create an endless loop with this code.

Comment: It probably repeats forever because jsfiddle is a thinner UI, so the last column will always be taller than 800px, so it'll recur forever. You'll probably want to set a boolean flag for if you have or haven't triggered that option yet, so that it doesn't continue trying to add that last page

Comment: also, the `#bios` has been added to `.page:last .last.column` immediately before calling buildNewsletter(), but buildNewsletter() is looking for its content inside of `#newsletterContent`. Once the height check fails, you'll want to append `#bios` to the `#newsletterContent` before calling buildNewsletter()